# A1 not being detected and case sensitivity

Tags: vba, excel

I got a code with the help of a friend but it's not detecting the first row. This code is going to delete rows that don't begin with certain letters.

I have to run it multiple times to delete unnecessary cells, but the A1 (which has an item to be deleted), was not removed.

```
Sub colortargets()

Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Activate
Do Until ActiveCell.Row = 1

If Left(ActiveCell.Value, 2) <> "AB" And Left(ActiveCell.Value, 2) <> "AC" And Left(ActiveCell.Value, 2) <> "AD" Then
Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Delete
End If

ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Activate

Loop

Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Also, is there a way to keep this code from being case-sensitive? It's really my first time to get around VBA so I'm kinda lost about what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this
it's because of `Do Until ActiveCell.Row = 1` condition that exits loop right when it reaches first row, without *treating* it

you may want to both avoid `Activate`/`ActiveXXX` pattern and use a different looping approach:

```
Option Explicit

Sub colortargets()
    Dim val As String
    Dim iRow As Long

    For iRow = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row To 1 Step -1
        val = Left(Cells(iRow, 1).Value, 2)
        If val <> "AB" And val <> "AC" And val <> "AD" Then Rows(iRow).Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

and if you have to make it case insensitive:

```
Option Explicit

Sub colortargets()
    Dim val As String
    Dim iRow As Long

    For iRow = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row To 1 Step -1
        val = UCase(Left(Cells(iRow, 1).Value, 2))
        If val <> "AB" And val <> "AC" And val <> "AD" Then Rows(iRow).Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Gee, thanks! Works perfectly! And I don't have to click multiple times to complete the filtering process.

Comment: And i'll take note of your note re Do Until. :D

Comment: Also, I'm applying the same approach here to a different set of codes that also don't treat the first row. Thanks again!

Comment: Tried, but didn't work on the different code. For this, cells should change color if they start with specific letters. The original code is below though I don't know how to format it like your response.